# Expo application freezes inside Android Emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, expo

After running the command `expo start --android` , I received an error message of request time out. Upon clicking on Retry, this screen appeared and my application never gets launched:

[image]

How can I get rid of it and what can be the root cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

solved: I relaunched my application on an another emulator.